# Bootstrap Masonry leaves empty spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a script from a cowboy developer, which I later paid to fix, but haven't received any reply. The demo is here: http://demos.eliteworks.info/sbd/

It's bootstrap based. Basically as you can see the masonry leaves empty spaces between items, I have tried everything I could as a newbie, but I'm not getting anywhere. Could someone just give me a clue what could be wrong, I will dig further myself, I'm not expecting ready result. Many thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me like Masonry is being called at all. The bootstrap columns are just cascading naturally and falling into place that way because of different heights.